# In Python, decoding hex file to decimal 'literal' equivalent

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, hex

I have a hex file of the first 100 million digits of pi after the decimal, in a hex editor it looks like this:

```
14 15 92 65 35 89 79 32 etc.
```

I need to convert this to the string (and eventually integer) '1415926435897932' etc. So it does not need to be 'converted' from hex to decimal, it's already decimal, just as hex bytes. (I used the word 'literal' in quotes in the title, it's probably totally the wrong word since it implies a string literal.)

When I try to read the file in python, I get all kinds of encoding difficulties (because the first byte, 15, is a non-printing character, etc.)

For example:

```
>>> f = open('pi100m.hexbin.000', 'rb')
>>> contents = f.read()
>>> f.close()
>>> snippet = contents[:50]
>>> snippet
'\x14\x15\x92e5\x89y28F&C82yP(\x84\x19qi9\x93u\x10X \x97IDY#\x07\x81d\x06(b\x08\x99\x86(\x03H%4!\x17\x06y'
>>> # if I 'print snippet', I get those question marks in triangles
>>> # for the nonprinting characters, they do not reproduce
>>> # in stackoverflow
```

I've tried lots of StackOverflow articles and Python help docs about encoding, but I have the feeling I'm missing something quite basic.

Comment: maybe `''.join([str(ord(x)) for x in snippet])` ?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, the output of that expression is '202114610153137121505670386756501218040132...' At least it looks a lot less like nonsense than anything I've gotten to date!

Comment: sorry my bad `''.join([hex(ord(x))[2:] for x in snippet])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encode *to* hex, then you at least have a string representation:

```
integer_string = contents.encode('hex')
```

Demo:

```
>>> snippet = '\x14\x15\x92e5\x89y28F&C82yP(\x84\x19qi9\x93u\x10X \x97IDY#\x07\x81d\x06(b\x08\x99\x86(\x03H%4!\x17\x06y'
>>> snippet.encode('hex')
'1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679'
```

This essentially does what your hex editor does, represent the bytes as hex characters.

Comment: Like I suspected, I was missing something darned basic. I failed to realize one could use 'hex' for and encode argument... don't know how I missed that in the docs. Thank you, good sir!

Answer (score 1):

```
snippet = '\x14\x15\x92e5\x89y28F&C82yP(\x84\x19qi9\x93u\x10X \x97IDY#\x07\x81d\x06(b\x08\x99\x86(\x03H%4!\x17\x06y'
''.join([str(ord(x)/16)+str(ord(x)%16) for x in snippet])
```

.

```
'1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679'
```